# How to apply the Relation between net acceleration and time in this case?

Tags: gravity, acceleration

I have a small doubt ... I read online about some elevator problems and concluded that , 
If a body is falling downwards, the net acceleration of the body is = acc.due to gravity - acc. of the body 
If a body is moving upwards , the net acceleration of the body is = acc.due to gravity + acc. of the body .
So does this mean that if throw a body downwards from some height with some acceleration , the net acceleration of the body will reduce and the body will take more time to reach the ground in comparison to another body just dropped from the same height ? I am not getting this . I am not able to figure out my misconception. i woukd be thankful with some clears my misconception . Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where you read that, but  "net acceleration of the body is = acc.due to gravity - acc. of the body" does not much sense to me. Usually, you calculate the net acceleration of a body once you know what forces are acting on it. For a body under free fall, the acceleration will be "g", the acceleration of gravity because it is the only force that acts. This is regardless of the initial speed downwards that you give to body. The misunderstanding could be that you think that you can give an initial acceleration to the body and the body will keep this acceleration. But this is incorrect. What the body will keep as the initial velocity the one it had when you stopped touching it.  Once you do not touch it anymore, the only force on the object will be gravity, so the acceleration will be g. If there is an initial speed downwards, the body will get to the ground faster than one that is just dropped with zero speed. So your intuition was correct.

Comment: U actually made things as clear as possible. What u stated as my misconception was exactly true . Dont know from where did u get that mind connection with me . Ur answer is apt and amazing for my query . Thanks a lot Sir . I really mean that...

Comment: you are welcomed! There is no mind trick, I had a lot of students and that misconception is not uncommon.